# How to incorporate msiexec parameters in a mst

Tags: group-policy, msi

I'm using the Orca tool from Microsoft to create a transform to be used in a gpo deployment. I wonder how to edit the msi to get the same result as this commandline will get me:

```
msiexec /qn+ /i setup.msi FOO_SETTING=BAR_VALUE
```

In what table in the msi do I put FOO_SETTING=BAR_VALUE ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Property table.

Comment: Boy do I feel stupid.